# return a value depending on condition

Tags: c#, if-statement, methods, return, extension-methods

Assuming I have the following extension method:

```
public static string sampleMethod(this int num) {
    return "Valid";
}
```

how can I terminate `sampleMethod` and show a messagebox if `num > 25` ?

If I try below code,I receive a red underline on the `sampleMethod` and says `not all code path returns a value`.

```
public static string sampleMethod(this int num) {
    if(num > 25) {
        MessageBox.Show("Integer must not exceed 25 !");
    } else {
        return "Valid String";
    }
}
```

and if I add `throw new Exception("...");` under the `MessageBox.Show`, everything goes well but the application terminates.

how can I show the MessageBox and terminate the Method instead if the condition is not met ?

Thank you.

Comment: i know i can do this outside the method my adding an `if-statement` that throws the `num` to the `sampleMethod` if `num <= 25` but i want to know if i can do this inside the `sampleMethod`

Comment: I see your `if (num > 25)` condition didn't have any return statement after MessageBox.Show, your sampleMethod requires return a string value on every condition e.g.`return "Invalid String"`.

Comment: because the function will return a value from my `List Object` and the `num` will be used as an `indexer` in the `List Object`. and the `List Object` contains strings. say `num = 25` and `lstObject[num] = "Lorem Ipsum"`, then `"Lorem Ipsum"` will be returned and used on the main program. i wouldnt want to return an "Invalid String" that will be added to the string afterward. instead, i want to terminate the method or not return anything if `num > 25`

Comment: If you don't want to return any string after the num exceeds 25, use `String.Empty` as method's return value. I will explain it in answer section.

Comment: Is this extension method actually being added to an `int`? Because it wouldn't be very nice nor logical for an `int` to have a method that opens a `MessageBox`!! I think this method shouldn't do that and you should display all messages from the caller. You will have to do some checking of `sampleMethod` return value in the caller method anyway, so why don't keep that logic there?

Comment: the extension uses the `int` as an `indexer` in a `List` Object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you always return a `string` (since string is your return value) to all possible outcome/path of your function

```
public static string sampleMethod(this int num) {
    if(num > 25) {
        MessageBox.Show("Integer must not exceed 25 !");
        return "";
    }

    return "Valid String";
}
```

your code didn't work because

```
public static string sampleMethod(this int num) {
    if(num > 25) {
        MessageBox.Show("Integer must not exceed 25 !");
        // when it go to this block, it is not returning anything
    } else {
        return "Valid String";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have array of strings with 25 indexes:

```
public String[] data = new String[25] { /* declare strings here, e.g. "Lorem Ipsum" */ }

// indexer
public String this [int num]
{
    get
    {
        return data[num];
    }
    set
    {
        data[num] = value;
    }
}
```

The method should be changed as below if you not want to return any string when the array index exceeds 25:

```
public static String sampleMethod(this int num) {
    if(num > 25) {
        MessageBox.Show("Integer must not exceed 25 !");
        return String.Empty; // this won't provide any string value
    } else {
        return "Valid String";
    }
}
```